# How is message sent over message api faster than bluetooth socket?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have developed two android apps - one in watch and one in smart phone. The watch app can recognize a set of gestures and display them in watch as well as in phone(via bluetooth).

So I was exploring ways to send data from smart watch to smart phone. I came across bluetooth socket and message api. I implemented both and found out that message api is faster and doesn't miss any data(via bluetooth socket, I have seen messages not reaching the phone). So I would like to know how message api is faster and doesn't miss any data. Thanks in advance.